# Comparing rational numbers

Tags: algorithms, integers

Given $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb N$ and $b,d \notin \{0\}$,

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac a b < \frac c d &\iff& ad < cb
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

My questions are:

Given $a,b,c,d$

1. Assuming we can decide $x < y \in \mathbb Z$ in $\mathcal{O}(|x| +|y|)$, is there any way of deciding $ad<cb$ without having to preform the multiplications (or divisions), $a\cdot d$ and $c \cdot b$. Or is there some sort of proof that there is no way.
2. Is there a faster method to compare rational numbers than multiplying out the denominators.

Comment: Multiplication is perhaps the simplest thing to do. Note that to make the decision, we need to process at least $O(|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|)$ bits. You can artificially do without multiplications : add $a$ to itself $d-1$ times instead of doing $a.d$ directly. But surely this isn't what you are looking for?

Comment: @PKG but multiplication will take more than linear time. I think we want something faster for this question.

Comment: @PKG no that isn't what I am looking for, that is in fact $$\mathcal{O}(d)$$ and thus much slower. The question asks for something faster, for example a linear time algorithm such as an algorithm that runs in $$\mathcal{O}(|a| + |b| + |c| + |d|)$$. Or, a proof that no such algorithm exists (unless multiplication is itself linear).

Comment: The tricky case is when one interval contains another, e.g. $[a,d] \subset [b,c]$.

Comment: You implicitly assume that $b$ and $d$ have the same sign. Otherwise, the inequality direction changes.

Comment: @RanG. Thanks, edited to $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: (1) Multiplication is almost linear (search for Fürer's algorithm). (2) A "rational integer", at least in the context of algebraic number theory, actually just means an integer. You want to say "rational" or "rational number".

Comment: @YuvalFilmus (1) Almost, but it is not known to be linear. The question is exactly that; can this problem be solved faster than multiplication can (assuming multiplication is not linear time, or that they both run in linear time). (2) Thank you, corrected.

Comment: Quick idea: can you compute the position of the left-most $1$ in the binary representation of either product from the left-most ones in the factors? If so, you can probably sweep the binary representations of the four numbers, padded to the same length by leading zeroes, from the left and decide which product has the first one the other doesn't have.

Comment: @RealzSlaw: In that case you'd have to find the next difference; that can only be caused by something even farther right (?), so linear time should suffice. If this idea works at all, I have not thought it through completely.

Comment: @RealzSlaw: Wouldn't the first difference tell you which product is larger? (I am seriously puzzled, plus it's late over here.)

Comment: @Raphael doh you are right. Now lemme think if we can formulate this somehow.

Comment: @Raphael wouldn't getting the middle bits be as hard as multiplication itself? I don't see a way to "skip" to the next different bit, without computing them all along the way.

Comment: see also apparent duplicate [How to compare rational numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286761/how-to-compare-rational-numbers)

Answer (score 7):

My current research:

### Initial attempt at some general rules

One can try to make some general rules for solving the rational comparison:

Assuming all positive $a,b,c,d$:

$$
a < b \wedge c \ge d
 \Longrightarrow 
\frac a b < \frac c d\\
$$
This basically means, if the left side is less than one, and the right side is at least one, the left side is less than the right side. In the same vein:

$$
a \ge b \wedge c \le d
 \Longrightarrow 
\frac a b \not\lt \frac c d\\
$$

Another rule:

$$
(b > d) \wedge (a \le c)
 \Rightarrow
\left[\frac a b < \frac c d\right]
$$
I think of this rule as logical, since the greater the denominator, the smaller the number, while the greater the numerator, the larger the number. Hence if the left side has a greater denominator *and* a smaller numerator, the left will be smaller.

From here on in, we will assume that $a<c \wedge b < d$, because otherwise we can either solve it with the rules above, or reverse the question to $\frac c d \overset ? < \frac a b$, and we end up with this condition anyhow.

**Rules**:
$$
\left.
\\
\frac {(b-a)} b < \frac {(d-c)} d
 \iff
\left[\frac a b < \frac c d\right]
\right|_{a<c,b<d} \\
$$
This rule basically states that you can always subtract the numerators from the denominators, and set the results as the numerators, to obtain an equivalent problem. I'll leave out the proof.

$$
\left.
\\
\frac {a} b < \frac {c-a} {d-b}
 \iff
\left[\frac a b < \frac c d\right]
\right|_{a<c,b<d} \\
$$

This rule allows you to subtract the left numerator and denominator from the right numerator and denominator for an equivalent problem.

And of course there is scaling:

$$
\left.
\\
\frac {ak} {bk} < \frac {c} {d}
 \iff
\left[\frac a b < \frac c d\right]
\right|_{a<c,b<d} \\
$$
You can use scaling to make the subtraction rules above more significant.

Using these rules you can play around with things, apply them repeatedly, in smart combinations, but there are cases where numbers are close, and pathological.

By applying the previous rules, you can reduce all these problems to:
$$
\left.
\frac a b < \frac {ap+q} {bp'+q'}
\iff
\frac a b < \frac {q} {q'}
\right|_{a>q,b>q'}
$$

Sometimes you can solve this directly now, sometimes not. The pathological cases are usually in the form:

$$
\left.
\frac a b < \frac {c} {d}
\right|_{a>c,b>d,c\in \mathcal O(a), d \in \mathcal O(b)}
$$

Then you flip it, and result in the same thing, just with one bit less. Each application of the rules + flip reduces it by a digit/bit. AFAICT, you cannot quickly solve it, unless you apply the rules $\mathcal O(n)$ times (once for each digit/bit) in the pathological case, negating their seeming advantage.

### Open problem??

I realized that this problem seems to be harder than some current open problems.

An even weaker problem is to determine:

$$ad \overset ? = bc$$

And yet weaker:

$$ad \overset ? = c$$

This is the open problem of *verifying multiplication*. It is weaker, because if you had a way to determine $ad \overset ? < bc$, then you can easily determine $ad \overset ? = bc$, by testing using the algorithm twice, $ad \overset ? < bc$, $bc \overset ? < ad$. Iff either is true, you know that $ad \ne bc $.

Now, $ad \overset ? = c$ was an open problem, at least in 1986:

> The complexity of multiplication and division. Let us begin with the very 
>   simple equation ax = b. When considered over the integers, testing its solvability and finding a solution x is possible by integer division with remainder zero. For checking a given solution x, integer multiplication will suffice, but it is an interesting open problem whether there are faster methods of verification.
>
> ― [ARNOLD SCHÖNHAGE in Equation Solving in Terms of 
>   Computational Complexity](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1986.1/Main/icm1986.1.0131.0153.ocr.pdf)

Very interestingly, he also mentioned the question of *verifying matrix multiplication*:

> It is also an interesting question whether
>   verification of matrix multiplication, i.e., checking whether AB = G for given C, 
>   could possibly be done faster.
>
> ― [ARNOLD SCHÖNHAGE in Equation Solving in Terms of 
>   Computational Complexity](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1986.1/Main/icm1986.1.0131.0153.ocr.pdf)

This has been since solved, and it is indeed possible to verify in $\mathcal O(n^2)$ time with a randomized algorithm (with $n\times n$ being the size of the input matrices, so it is basically linear-time in the size of the input). I wonder if it is possible to reduce integer multiplication to matrix multiplication, especially with their similarities, given Karatsuba integer multiplication's similarities to matrix multiplication algorithms that followed. Then perhaps in some way we can leverage the matrix multiplication verification algorithm for integer multiplication.

Anyway, since this is still, to my knowledge, an open problem, the stronger problem of $ad \overset ? < cd$ is surely open. I am curious if solving the equality verification problem would have any bearing on the comparison inequality verification problem.

A slight variation of our problem would be if the fractions are guaranteed to be reduced to lowest terms; in this case it is easy to tell if $\frac a b \overset ? = \frac c d$. Can this have any bearing on comparison verification for reduced fractions?

An even subtler question, what if we had a way to test $ad \overset ? < c$, would this extend to testing $ad \overset ? = c$? I don't see how you can use this "both ways" like we did for $ad \overset ? < cd$.

Related:

- [Approximate Recognition of Non-regular Languages by Finite Automata](http://crpit.com/confpapers/CRPITV38Eisman.pdf)

  They do some work on approximate multiplication, and randomized verification, which I do not fully understand.
- [math.SE: How to Compare two multiplications without multiplying?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14268/39567)
- Suppose we were allowed to preprocess $c$ as much as we wanted in polynomial time, can we solve $ab=c$ in linear time?
- Is there a linear-time nondetermistic integer multiplication algorithm? See http://compgroups.net/comp.theory/nondeterministic-linear-time-multiplication/1129399

  > There are well-known algorithms for multiplying n-bit numbers with
  >   something like O(n log(n) log(log(n))) complexity. And we can't do
  >   better than O(n) because at least we have to look at the entire
  >   inputs. My question is: can we actually reach O(n) for a suitable
  >   class of "nondeterministic" algorithms?
  >
  > More precisely, is there an algorithm that can accept two n-bit
  >   binary numbers "a" and "b" and a 2n-bit number "c" and tell you in
  >   O(n) time whether "a * b = c"? If not, is there some other form of
  >   certificate C(a,b,c) such that an algorithm can use it to test the
  >   product in linear time? If not linear time, is the problem of
  >   testing the product at least asymptotically easier than computing
  >   it? Any known results along these lines would be welcome.
  >
  > John.
  >
  > ―johnh4717

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *very partial attempt* at disproof. Suppose that we can make use only of a (constant number of ) additions and subtractions in our decider, as well as a constant number of ${mod}$ w.r.t predefined numbers. In other words, we can do a constant number of $mod\ 2$, $mod\ 3$, etc. in our decider.  Then the only quantities we can compute are of the form $q = k_1 a +k_2 b+k_3 c + k_4 d  = \sum k_ia$ where the $k$'s are predefined constants. Note that $q$ can be computed in time $O(\sum|a|)$.

**Edited**
This decider purports to determine a bit $B:B=1$ iff $ad>bc$.  Consider taking $a,b,c,d$ as points in $\mathbb{R}^4$. The bit $B$ is decided by its position wrt the surface $ad = bc$ which is a hyperboloid in 4 dimensions. If we have a point $(a,b,c,d)$ in the input space, the decider above can compute points within a bounded distance of this input point, i.e. those points $q: |q-a| = k_1,$ etc. This defines a cuboid in 4 d space.

(How to make this more precise?) The distance from the cuboid to the surface is in general unbounded, and hence the surface can't be computed by the decider

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond to this. I think this might simply be above my understanding, and I've been busy researching possible answers myself in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Would you accept level of confidence?

Perhaps do approximate division. I.e.

To compute the bounding approximate quotients of a/b, right shift a by ceil(log_2(b)) and also by floor(log_2(b)). Then we know the accurate quotient is between these two values.

Then, depending on the relative sizes of the four integers, one may be able to rule out certain cases, and get 100% confidence.

One may repeat the procedure for radix other than 2, and by a succession of such operations increase the level of confidence, until a change of sign / tie-break is somehow observed?

That's my first-draft sketch of a method.

Comment: If you look at my "current research" answer, I think those rules do something to this effect. You can keep going, many times getting 100% confidence if it hits one of the first rules, and in the worst, you keep repeating the latter rules over and over removing a bit each round, similarly to what you are suggesting, I think. However, my question is about something definitive in $\mathcal O(n)$ (or rather, better than multiplication, $\mathcal O(n \log n)$ would satisfy this question too), or at least a randomized algorithm with some exponentially small probability of failure.

Comment: Also, if one could verify that this is an open problem, and not somehow inherently harder than verifying $ab=c$ (see my "current research" answer, section **Open Problem??**), or if there is some other interesting existing research or results about this, then that too could be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way of deciding ad < cb without having to preform the [expensive] multiplications

Sure.

*Idea:* Compare the decimal expansion bit by bit.

The only nasty bit is that we have to exclude equality first because otherwise
we may not terminate.
It is useful to first compare the integer parts because that is easy.

Consider this:

```scala
def less( (a,b), (c,d) ) = {
  // Compare integer parts first
  intA = a div b
  intC = c div d

  if intA < intB
    return True
  else if intA > intB
    return False
  else // intA == intB
    // Normalize to a number in [0,1]
    a = a mod b
    c = c mod d

    // Check for equality by reducing both
    // fractions to lowest terms
    (a,b) = lowestTerms(a,b)
    (c,d) = lowestTerms(c,d)

    if a == c and b == d
      return False
    else
      do
        // Compute next digits in decimal fraction 
        a = 10 * a
        c = 10 * c

        intA = a div b
        intC = c div d

        // Remove integer part again
        a = a mod b
        c = c mod d
      while intA == intC

      return intA < intC
    end
  end
}
```

Note that the `do-while` loop has to terminate since the numbers are unequal.
We do not know how long it runs, though; if the numbers are very close, it could
be a while.

Clearly, there are no expensive multiplications; the only ones we need is
to multiply the nominators by $10$. In particular, we have avoided computing
$ad$ and $cb$ explicitly.

Is this fast? Probably not. There are lots of integer divisons, modulos and `gdc`s
to compute, and we have a loop whose number of iterations is inversly proportional
to the distance between the numbers we compare.

---

The helper method:

```scala
def lowestTerms(a,b) = {
  d = gcd(a,b)
  if d == 1
    return (a,b)
  else
    return lowestTerms(a div d, b div d)
  end
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is in the spirit of the question. Computing $a/b$ and $c/d$ right at the start already takes as much time as computing $ad$ and $bc$ in the question, and the question already says "without... the multiplications (or divisions), $a\cdot d$ and $c\cdot b$". It also asks for a linear time algorithm, which I'm guessing this isn't, based on your comment about the loop running for a while.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Hm. I was thinking about overflows mainly -- here, the operations are less likely to create huge numbers.